# Finding arc lenght of a curve in $R^3$

Tags: calculus, arc-length

I'm trying to find the arc lenght of a curve in $R^3$. I know that that the formula to find this is $\int_a^b \sqrt{f'(t)^2 + g'(t)^2+h'(t)^2}dt$.

But I want to find the arc lenght between the points $(\frac{1}{3},1,5)$ and $(9,5,13)$ of a curve $\vec{C} = \frac{t^3}{3}, 2t-1,t^2+4)$

So I am confused as to what my $a$ and $b$ would be in thi case? as I have a curve in $R^3$. so the interval [a,b] is not a single value? as I have three values, x,y z.

Do you get what I mean?

Comment: a,b are same as t when the arc starts and when the arc ends. i.e. a means t=1 and b means t=3

Comment: I can't see why a=1 and b=3

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the $t$-values for which $C$ passes through the given points. It is easy to see that $$C(1)=\left(\frac{1}{3},1,5\right)\quad\mbox{and}\quad C(3)=(9,5,13),$$and since $C$ is injective (because of the first component), there are no ambiguities or other possibilities. The arclength is $$\int_1^3((t^2)^2+2^2+(2t)^2)^{1/2}\,{\rm d}t.$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe a and b are the value of the parameter at the initial point and the final point since the integral integrates over the "speeds" (the magnitude of the derivative) at every value of the parameter between a and b. At $(\frac{1}{3}, 1, 5)$ $t=1$ and at $(9,5,13)$ $t=3$, so $a=1$ and $b=3$.

Comment: I understand its the start and end point, but I'm confused as to why it is a=1 and b=3?

Comment: The value of t at $(\frac{1}{3}, 1, 5)$ is 1, since $\frac{1^3}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$, $2(1)^2-1=1$ and $1^2+4=5$. Similarly the value of t at (9,5,13) is 3. So you're finding the arc length between the point where t=1 and t=3